# A (quantifier-free) is true in standard model of PA ==> PA |- A ??

Tags: peano-axioms

### Is the following statement correct ?

A is a formula in PA without a quantifier and
A is true for the standard model of arithmetic, i.e. the model 
|N = (N,+,×,0,1,<)
This means: |N |= A

==>

A is proofable in PA. This means:
PA |- A

Example:
|N |= (x+y)^2 =x^2 + 2xy + y^2
===>
PA |- (x+y)^2 =x^2 + 2xy + y^2

If this statement is wrong, please give me a counterexample

cu
cx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$
\text{You gave a counterexample: true in N but not PA-provable.} \\
\text{But there are so many examples with: true in N and PA-provable: } \\
\text{I define: } \\
\text{I_N} = \{0,1,2, ...\} \text{ is the set of intuitive natural numbers} \\
\bar 0 \; and \; \bar 1     \text{ are the constants from PA} \\
\oplus  and \circ      \text{ are the functions in PA} \\
\text{when z is element from I_N, I define:} \\
\bar z :=  \bar 1 \oplus ... \oplus + \bar 1   \quad \text{n-times} \\
\text{I proofed the following statement "S1"} \\
\text{When n is element from I_N then we have:} \\
PA \vdash \forall x \forall y  \; (\bar z = x \oplus y \quad .\rightarrow. \quad
\bigvee_{i=0}^z (x=\bar i \land y=\overline{z-i}) \\
\text{I assume, that there are "many" of "similar" statements like S1.} \\
\text{Is it possible to formulate a statement "S", so that "S1" follows from "S" ?} \\
$$

cu 
cx

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: It looks like I misread your question. There is an important difference between quantifier-free *sentences*, which is what my original answer (now below the fold) addressed, and quantifier-free *formulas*. Namely, when you speak of PA proving a formula with free variables *(or of a structure satisfying such a formula)*, you're really asking about PA proving *(or a structure satisfying)* the **universal closure** of a quantifier-free formula: e.g. $$PA\vdash (x+y)^2=x^2+2x+y^2$$ is really shorthand for $$PA\vdash\forall x,y((x+y)^2=x^2+2x+y^2).$$

Such statements are **no longer provable** in PA in general. For example, it's essentially a consequence of the [MRDP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_set) that there is a Diophantine equation $t_1(x_1,..,x_n)=t_2(x_1,...,x_n)$ which has no solutions but which PA can't prove has no solutions; then the quantifier-free formula $$\neg(t_1(x_1,...,x_n)=t_2(x_1,...,x_n))$$ is true in $\mathbb{N}$ but not PA-provable.

---

What if we don't work with implicit universal quantifiers - that is, we restrict attention to **sentences** (= formulas with no free variables)? *This was the original - incorrect - way I interpreted your question.*

Here we get a positive result: PA proves every true [$\Sigma_1$ sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy) (that is, every sentence of the form $\exists x_1...\exists x_n\varphi(x_1,...,x_n)$, where $\varphi$ uses only bounded quantifiers). This fact ("$\Sigma_1$-completeness") about PA does *not* depend on PA being consistent - it is provable in PA itself, or indeed much less. The proof is tedious but not hard. Under the further assumption that PA is $\Sigma_1$-sound, this implies that the true $\Sigma_1$-sentences are *exactly* those which PA proves.

So this **exactly** delineates PA's power in terms of the coarse arithmetic hierarchy: PA proves exactly the correct $\Sigma_1$ sentences (under a reasonable assumption on PA), but there are correct $\Pi_1$ sentences which PA doesn't prove.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.
I tried to proof my statement, but I could not do it. My idee: every  term represent as a polynom.
Please can you give me a link to the proof of my statement.

cu cx

Comment: @user508589 Looking at your question again, I misread it (the issue being "formula" versus "sentence" and the implicit universal quantifier when we talk about proving/satisfying the former). I've edited.